# Conditional convergence equivalents

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

Given $\sum (-1)^n a_n $ such that $a_n >0$ , my question is :

does $\sum (-1)^n a_n $ converges if and only if $\sum a_{2k-1}-a_{2k} $ converges   ?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question?

Comment: What if $a_n=1$?

Comment: @amWhy i think it does, but the theorem we learned is we could cluster and the equivalent is reserved if the numbers in the parenthesis have the same sign, i am asking if one is positive and the other is negative.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla is there a necessary and sufficient conditions for this to hold true ?

Comment: If we require additionally $\lim a_n = 0$, then your equivalence is true.

Comment: Or, alternately, require $\lim_{k\to\infty}(a_{2k+1}-a_{2k})=0$